# How to call a method before back to the specific screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a ui screen to show the data query from local database, to let this ui data sync with the local data source, i need to call a db.query method before navigation like Get.back() and Get.off().

I also think about using .obs variable in GetxController, but when data coming from service like background push, it can not access to  the getx state.

Answer (score 1):

Either put your method in..

```
   WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async { //method },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
```

or

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    //method
    super.dispose();
  }
```

`WillPopScope` handles the back button while `dispose()` gets called when ever the widget is destroyed